# How to correctly handle no recurring charges

Tags: shopify

Our app (CustomerSure) is currently failing to check whether a certain Shopify customer has an active recurring charge which we use to set our internal status. In the partner area it shows that their charge is currently "frozen".

What causes the recurring charge to be frozen and is the charge still present on their account?

Currently our call to check for a current charge (`ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.current`) is raising an exception, undefined method find called on nil, `.all` appears to be the culprit, see:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/recurring_application_charge.rb#L7

Should we be checking an overall account status before asking for the current charge or is this an oversite in the gem that needs to check for a `nil` return on `.all`?

Answer (score 0):

Frozen charges are due to the shop’s own account being frozen due to it no longer being in good standing. Usually the reason behind this is due to the merchant forgetting to update their credit card information after their credit card expires.

If the `shopify_api` gem is throwing an exception after calling `ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.current` then that sounds like a bug, so posting it to… oh, you’ve already sent it to the [right GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/issues/38). Thanks!